# Is this possible to receive a broadcast without adding permission in manifest file

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

If an application is broadcasting with permissions i.e. receiver should have some particular permission to be able to receive the broadcast.

Can there be some other way to receive this broadcast without adding permission in the manifest file?

I am just trying to now how powerful are permissions...not for a wrong purpose.

Comment: Without using permission how can you identify which broadcast has done and weather your application should respond to that broadcast or not?

Comment: The intent filter specifies which broadcast this receiver is listening for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the main security concepts of Android that every activity needs to request the permissions which it would like to use in its app.

If it would be possible to register some broadcastreceiver without the specific permissions in the manifest file, it would be easy to compromise the system.

Answer (score 0):

its not neccessary to declare BroadcastReceiver in menifest file.You can also do it in java code like this.

```
IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! But, for this we need to add android.permission.BATTERY_STATS permission in the manifest file. I want to know, can there be a way to get this broadcast intent without this permission

Comment: The Activity or other component having this BroadcastReceiver needs to have the permission I guess? Or how is this handled.

Comment: I dont think so that there's any feature provided by Google to receive any broadcast without adding permission in the manifest file.